# Issue Reading JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am having a hard time reading the following JSON (basically no errors and nothing happens) and was hoping to get help identifying the issue with the function. I am unclear if the ajax is successful at grabbing it or if it's just not reading it correctly afterwards. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the structure of the JSON response:

```
   [{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Account/00130000015KJlWAAW"},"id":"00130000015KJlWAAW","locname":"Central Valley Ag","address":"607 North Robinson","city":"Hartington","state":"NE","postal":"68739","phone":"402-254-3354","web":"","lat":"42.627212","lng":"-97.269283"},{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Account/00130000015KJlXAAW"},"id":"00130000015KJlXAAW","locname":"Central Valley Ag","address":"709 Centennial Rd","city":"Wayne","state":"NE","postal":"68787","phone":"402-375-3510","web":"","lat":"42.235756","lng":"-96.998321"}]
```

---

This is the portion of the script which processes the JSON:

```
   function mapping(orig_lat, orig_lng, origin) {
                $(function () {
                    var dataType;
                    //jsonData is set to true
                    if (settings.jsonData == true) {
                        dataType = "jsonp";
                    } else {
                        dataType = "xml";
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: settings.dataLocation,
                        dataType: dataType,
                        crossDomain: true,                            
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {   
                    alert('Error Message: '+textStatus);
                    alert('HTTP Error: '+errorThrown);
                },
                        success: function (data) {
                            //After the store locations file has been read successfully
                            var i = 0;

                            if (settings.jsonData == true) {
                                var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                                //Process JSON
                                $.each(data, function () {
                                    var name = this.locname;
                                    var lat = this.lat;
                                    var lng = this.lng;
                                    var address = this.address;
                                    var address2 = this.address2;
                                    var city = this.city;
                                    var state = this.state;
                                    var postal = this.postal;
                                    var phone = this.phone;
                                    var web = this.web;
                                    web = web.replace("http://", "");
                                    var distance = GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistance(orig_lat, orig_lng, lat, lng, GeoCodeCalc.EarthRadiusInMiles);
                                    //Create the array
                                    locationset[i] = new Array(distance, name, lat, lng, address, address2, city, state, postal, phone, web);
                                    i++;
                                });
                            } else {
                                //Process XML
                                $(data).find('marker').each(function () {
                                    //Take the lat lng from the user, geocoded above
                                    var name = $(this).attr('name');
                                    var lat = $(this).attr('lat');
                                    var lng = $(this).attr('lng');
                                    var address = $(this).attr('address');
                                    var address2 = $(this).attr('address2');
                                    var city = $(this).attr('city');
                                    var state = $(this).attr('state');
                                    var postal = $(this).attr('postal');
                                    var phone = $(this).attr('phone');
                                    var web = $(this).attr('web');
                                    web = web.replace("http://", "");
                                    var distance = GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistance(orig_lat, orig_lng, lat, lng, GeoCodeCalc.EarthRadiusInMiles);
                                    //Create the array
                                    locationset[i] = new Array(distance, name, lat, lng, address, address2, city, state, postal, phone, web);
                                    i++;
                                });
                            }
```

Update: I added an ajax error handler as states and get the following parseerror when the page is loaded:

HTTP Error:Error:
jQuery172036075869924388826_1343923258757 was not called

Then when I attempt to run the function I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'alert' of object [object Window] is not a function          dealer-locator-iframe2:273
$.fn.storeLocator.each.$.ajax.error dealer-locator-iframe2:273
f.Callbacks.o jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
w jquery.min.js:4
f.ajaxTransport.send.d.onload.d.onreadystatechange
```

Comment: @Onheiron - It's "jsonp" as in if (settings.jsonData == true) {
                        dataType = "jsonp";

Comment: your JSON is enclosed with [], this suggests me it might be interpreted as an array of objects. Try calling this[0].locname ... and sorry for the previous comment, I didn't read very well :D

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to run `$.parseJSON` on the `data` variable. `data` is coming back as a string of JSON and you need to convert it into a JavaScript object literal.

Example:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

So place this immediately after `if (settings.jsonData == true)` in your `success` function:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

The reason you're not getting any errors is because the `$.each(function() {....});` isn't looping, because there isn't anything to loop on a string.

There's a really easy way to test for the data type of the `data` variable. Use this at the beginning of your `success` function:

```
alert(typeof(data));
```

If you get `string` returned, then you know that's the problem.

Comment: The dataType can be set to JSON, but he's still getting back a string of JSON. That string of JSON needs to be parsed (i.e., safely eval'ed) into object notation.

Comment: Right solution, but I think the best place to put this code is before `$.each` - inside `if(setting.jsonData)` Because it will not cause any problem if there is XML data :)

Comment: Oh you're correct, I missed that if/then statement for JSON vs XML, answer updated.

Comment: @ElliotB. I am not getting anything returned when I alert(typeof(data)); So I think I might need to set an ajax error handler as epascarello states. Also, I added var data = $.parseJSON(data); and again nothing and no errors occurred.

Comment: @Onheiron I updated my post to include the error that I see - have you seen this before?

Comment: @McKev Could you update your code as well? It looks like the error is referencing something that is not in your code.

Comment: @ElliotB. I updated the code - In addition to the error handler, I also added: crossDomain: true

Comment: @McKev Looks like you're missing a `});` at the end of your code-- `$.ajax` isn't fully enclosed.

Comment: did you try what I suggested in my comment at you question an reference your JSON element as this[0].state etc?

Comment: @ElliotB. No issue with closures.

Comment: @McKev It would be good if you updated your code above to reflect that. For all the people troubleshooting your issue on here, it's important to see everything--even the closing tags.

Comment: @ElliotB. Would this help - here is a link to the entire functionality: microessentials.com/dealer-locator2

Answer (score 0):

Before `$.each` add this line

```
data = eval("("+data+")");
```

and rest of your code will just work fine...

Why your code is not working?
Reason - Because your are trying to run your loop on the `string`.
First convert that `string` into the `JSON object`. `eval()` converts `string` to `javascript` object.

Comment: Running `eval` works but isn't the safest way to process inbound JSON strings, parsing methods such as `parseJSON` are preferred.

Comment: I think @Elliot B. way is the correct one if this is the issue, usually eval() should be used with caution.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the info guys, I wasn't aware of that :) Can you please tell me what problem I might have to face with `eval()` ? because I always use it... And I would like to start using `$.parseJSON` instead... I don't always use jQuery btw, So I am sticking with `eval()`.. I never observed any problem with `eval()` though :).. Just curious about it...

Comment: Simply eval() evaluates a string as if it was a command itself, but you can't be sure what's in there... let's say you don't know your server response which might be '{json:"goodJSO"} + mean code' if you call parseJSON it will just fail, if you call eval() it will execute the mean code in it.

Comment: With eval you're vulnerable to injection attacks where a hacker creates a bogus AJAX response that contains JS commands instead of proper JSON. $.parseJSON is designed to prevent injected commands from executing, whereas eval just executes everything without checks.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON looks like an array of objects, you can tell by those [] surrounding it. It is an array with just one element, but this gives errors if you write

```
json.key
```

because json is not an object but an array of objects, so   json.key looks like you are calling some fncion "key" in the array which is not there. You should first select the real object itself with json[0] like

```
myJson = json[0]
```

an then

```
value = myJson.key1
```

if you're using some external API it is likely to be this issue as I faced this before

Comment: If you take a look at this http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/ under the JSONP with jQuery section it says that it should handle it easily. I am starting to believe that there another issue. But I see the data perfectly fine. Here is the URL to my work: http://www.microessentials.com/dealer-locator2

Comment: but did you try my suggestion out? This is not a bug or an issue, simply the service doesn't know how many records match your get query so it puts every record in a JSON array, when I say it is an array doesn't mean it is not correct JSON, simply you should expect one or more matches an face the fact you'll have to handle them

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it had issues. It appears to be a callback issue with JSONP. It keeps telling me that it cannot call the data.

Comment: ok, I don'think it would change much, but try out .getJSON, it should handle the typing automatically http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/  also what exactly is that setting.dataLocation?

Comment: Yeah, I had .getJSON initially and changed it to JSONP as a resolution. As for the .dataLocation, http://mosaicco.force.com/siteforce/activeretailaccounts